# How to setup puppet master as a node

Tags: ssl, centos, puppet

Currently I have a master and agent working on separate Centos 6.5 VMs. I would like to be able to configure my own master as I will be tearing down and making a new master every time.

How can I get puppet agent --test --noop  to work on my master machine as well?
Currently I receive an error:

Error: Could not request certificate: 502 "Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. ISA Server is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )"

SSL requests seem to be setup for port 443. Any thoughts?

Thank you very much!
Jason

Comment: Does the master machine have a proxy configuration? You should try and make the puppet agent circumvent that.

Comment: puppet.conf from both nodes can be help for diagnostic. and probably `export | grep proxy ` from master node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Felix Frank, mr_tron

Issue seemed to be solved by removing http_proxy declaration in .bashrc file and anywhere else

Puppet Master now able to act as an agent

Thank you,
Jason